# Drawing Solids with LaTeX

Tags: packages, 3d, asymptote

I want to know if there is a package that automatically draw solids (spheres, cylinders, cubes, prisms).

I know I can do this kind of drawing using TikZ or PSTricks. But what about a package where you can type `\cube{2cm}` and it draws a cube of side 2 cm.

I am not posting a MWE because I just want to know if such package exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d). The package readme mentions:

The pack­age is de­signed to draw solids in 3D per­spec­tive. Fea­tures in­clude:

- cre­ate prim­i­tive solids;
- cre­ate solids by in­clud­ing a list of its ver­tices and faces;
- faces of solids and sur­faces can be col­ored by choos­ing from a very large palette of col­ors;
- draw para­met­ric sur­faces in al­ge­braic and re­verse pol­ish no­ta­tion;
- cre­ate ex­plicit and pa­ram­e­ter­ized al­ge­braic func­tions drawn in 2 or 3 di­men­sions;
- project text onto a plane and onto the faces of a solid;
- sup­port for in­clud­ing ex­ter­nal database files.

Here's a small example (compile with LaTeX or XeLaTeX):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\rule[-1cm]{2cm}{2cm} \qquad\qquad
%
\psset{viewpoint=100 30 20,Decran=100,unit=1cm}
\psSolid[object=cube,a=2,
  action=draw*,
  fillcolor=magenta!20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It can also simulate a point light source (which is really quite nice in my view) simply with an extra option such as `lightsrc=20 30 50` (light intensity can also be set). The thing that isn't great for me is that it is pstricks which I found tricky to get to work with pdflatex (I eventually got it working with auto-pst-pdf). I would have preferred to use something like sketch since it can output tikz, but pst-solides3d is just too perfect for the job.

Answer (score 16):

You might be interested in [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net), a vector graphics language that you uses TeX for labels and can be used from within LaTeX.

Asymptote can draw standard shapes (spheres, cylinders, cubes, etc) which you can then scale, rotate, and shift to create many other shapes. (Asymptote can also do many other things.)

Here's a brief example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
import three;
//Setup View
size(200);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2);

//Draw Axes
pen thickblack = black+0.75;
real axislength = 2.0;
draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(1.1), align=SW), -axislength*X--axislength*X,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$y$", position=Relative(1.1), align=E), -axislength*Y--axislength*Y,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$z$", position=Relative(1.1), align=N), -2*axislength*Z--2*axislength*Z,thickblack, Arrow3); 

//Define cube surfaces
surface c1 = unitcube;
surface c2 = shift(-2Z)*rotate(45,X)*c1;
surface s1 = unitsphere;
surface s2 = rotate(75,Z)*shift(1.5Z)*xscale3(2)*yscale3(0.5)*zscale3(0.1)*s1;

//Draw cube surfaces
draw(c1,palegrey);
draw(c2,green);
draw(s2,red);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great illustration! Suggestion in constructing `s2`: use `scale(2, 0.5, 0.1)`.

Comment: @mrc WinEdt "asymptote.sty" not found?

Comment: Actually `asymptote.sty` should be included in TeX Live, as should the alternative package `asypictureB` (if your package list was recently updated).

Comment: @CharlesStaats I was unaware for `asypictureB` . . . I am looking forward to not recompiling figures I haven't changed!. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

One can also use

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \textwidth = 19cm 
   \oddsidemargin = -1.7cm
   \evensidemargin = -1.4cm

   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{minipage}{0.23 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{Le cube}\vskip.3truecm 

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \draw[thick,black] (4,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) -- (4,4,0);
   \draw[thick,black]  (4,0,0) -- (4,0,-4) -- (4,4,-4) -- (4,4,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[thick,black](0,4,0) -- (0,4,-4) -- (4,4,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (4,0,-4) -- (0,0,-4)-- (0,4,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-4); 
   \draw[<->](0,-0.3,0)--(4,-0.3,0);
   \draw node[below] at (2,-0.3,0) {c}; 
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{Le pav\'e droit} \\
   (parall\'el\'epip\`ede rectangle)\vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \draw[thick,black] (6,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (6,3,0);
   \draw[thick,black]  (6,0,0) -- (6,0,-4) -- (6,3,-4) -- (6,3,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[thick,black](0,3,0) -- (0,3,-4) -- (6,3,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (6,0,-4) -- (0,0,-4)-- (0,3,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-4); 
   \draw[<->](-0.3,0,0)--(-0.3,3,0);
   \draw node[left] at (-0.3,1.5,0) {h}; 
   \draw[<->](0,-0.3,0)--(6,-0.3,0);
   \draw node[below] at (3,-0.3,0) {L}; 
   \draw[<->](6.3,0,0)--(6.3,0,-4);
   \draw node[below right] at (6.3,0,-2) {l}; 
   \end{tikzpicture}        

   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.23 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{Le prisme droit}\vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \draw[thick,black] (0,5,0)-- (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0)--(6,5,0)--(1,5,-3)--(0,5,0)--(6,5,0);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,-3)-- (1,5,-3);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black]  (1,0,-3)-- (6,0,0);
   \draw[thick,black] (1.5,0,-2.7)  --(1.5,0.5,-2.7)--(1,0.5,-3) ;
   \draw[thick,black] (0.9,0,-2.7)  --(0.9,0.5,-2.7)--(1,0.5,-3) ;
   \draw node[left] at (1,2.5,-3) {h};    
   \end{tikzpicture}


   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.23 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{Le cylindre}\vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
   \draw[thick,black](3,0,-2) ellipse (1.25 and 0.35);
   \draw[thick,black]  (1.75,-3,-2) arc (180:360:1.25 and 0.35);
   \draw [dashed]  (4.25,-3,-2) arc (0:180:1.25 and 0.35);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](3,-3,-2) -- (4.25,-3,-2);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](3,0,-2) -- (4.25,0,-2);          
   \draw node[above left] at (3.7,-0.1,-2) {r}; 
   \draw node[left] at (3,-2,-2) {h}; 
   \draw[thick,black]  (1.75,0,-2) --(1.75,-3,-2);
   \draw[thick,black]  (4.25,0,-2) --(4.25,-3,-2);
   \draw[thick,black] (3,-2.8,-2 ) --(3.2,-2.8,-2 ) --(3.2,-3,-2 );   
   \draw[thick,black, dashed] (3,0,-2)--(3,-3,-2 );
   \end{tikzpicture}


   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \vskip1truecm

   \begin{minipage}{0.3 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{La pyramide} \vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
   \draw[thick,black] (0,3,0)--(6,3,0)--(6,3,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](0,3,0) -- (0,3,-4) -- (6,3,-4);
   \draw[thick,black] (0,3,0) -- (3,9,-2) -- (6,3,0);
   \draw[thick,black]  (3,9,-2) -- (6,3,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](3,9,-2) -- (0,3,-4);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](3,9,-2) -- (3,3,-2);
   \draw[style=dashed, color=black](3,3,-2) -- (6,3,-2);
   \draw[thick,black] (3,3.2,-2 ) --(3.2,3.2,-2 ) --(3.2,3,-2 );
   \draw node[left] at (3,6,-2) {h};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.3 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{Le c\^one}  \vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[dashed] (0,0) arc (170:10:2cm and 0.4cm)coordinate[pos=0] (a);
   \draw[thick,black] (0,0) arc (-170:-10:2cm and 0.4cm)coordinate (b);
   \draw[densely dashed] ([yshift=4cm]$(a)!0.5!(b)$) --node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$h$}coordinate[pos=0.95] (aa)($(a)!0.5!(b)$)-- node[above,font=\footnotesize] {$r$}coordinate[pos=0.1] (bb) (b);
   \draw[thick,black] (aa) -| (bb);
   \draw[thick,black] (a) -- ([yshift=4cm]$(a)!0.5!(b)$) -- (b);
   \end{tikzpicture}


   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.3 \textwidth}

   \begin{center}
   \textbf{La sph\`ere - La boule}\vskip.3truecm

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
   \draw[thick,black](0,0) circle (2cm);
   \draw[thick,black](-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
   \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
   \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
   \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (2,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}


   \vskip.3truecm$Volume =\dotfill $ 
   \end{center}

   \end{minipage}
   \end{document}
```

which gives 
[image: Formula of the usual solides using tikz]