# Drawing solids with Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I want to draw the following [solids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406575/101831) with `asymptote`:

[image: Formula of the usual solides using tikz]

**My first steps**

After reading through the `asymptote` [manual](http://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/graphics/asymptote/doc/asymptote.pdf) I found on p. 156 the solids package. Sadly it isn't very well documented.

I modfied the only example to get the following solid:

```
import solids;

size(0,100);

revolution r = cylinder(O,1,1,Z);

draw(r);
```

[image]

**My questions**

1. How can I get the other solids?
2. How can I add labels?
3. How can I draw some of the lines or surfaces in a different color?

[Here is the link to the package.](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/base/solids.asy) (I'm not good at understanding this kind of code.)

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://www.cgmaths.fr/Atelier/Asymptote/ConesCylindres.html) and [here](https://www.cgmaths.fr/Atelier/Asymptote/CalottesSph.html) and search google for keyword **Dem_Rapide**.

Comment: And you also should take a look at https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Would it be okay with you if the background lines are faint rather than dashed?

Comment: If there is an easy solution with faint lines then the answer is yes.